# GET http://localhost:8000/add/ Page not found

Tags: python, django

I've been working on this application using my localhost:8000 for a while now and everything had been working smoothly. However now that I have tried to add a new url: /add/. For some reason it doesn't recognise the URL. I believe maybe there's something wrong with how I've wrote my code but I haven't quite found it. Any help would be great!

To provide context I started of in my urls.py file where I created a new path: `path('add', views.ProjectCreateView.as_view(), name='add'),`

I then moved over to my views.py file and imported the CreateView as so: 
`from django.views.generic import CreateView`.

From there I then created a class for the view:

```
class ProjectCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Project
    template_name = 'budget/add-project.html'
    fields = ('name', 'budget')
```

Following this I then created another file within my budget folder nested in my templates folder. The file name add-project.html. I don't think there's anything wrong with this file but just to guarantee this is how I linked my html file:

```
{% extends 'budget/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
```

This is the exact message I get when I run http://localhost:8000/add/

"No Project matches the given query."

ULRS.PY in main working folder:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.project_list, name='list'),
    path('add', views.ProjectCreateView.as_view(), name='add'),
    path('<slug:project_slug>/', views.project_detail, name='detail')
]
```

URLS.PY in subfolder:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib import admin



urlpatterns = [
       path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
       path('',include('budget.urls'))
   ]
```

Comment: can you share how have you defined Model? also don't you have to add a HTML form in your template? try adding your view in url as `url(r'add/$', ProjectCreateView.as_view(), name='project_add')`

Comment: please show the entire error trace.

Comment: oh and please show urls.py, I have the feeling that the wrong view is being used because a `CreateView` cannot be returning this error. Do you also have a `path('<something>')`?

Comment: This is the error message in my cmd: Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Not Found: /add/
[20/Sep/2019 19:31:24] "GET /add/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1727

Comment: seconding @dirkgroten here, also if you have multiple `urls.py` files, post all of them along with *where they are / their path* in the project

Comment: I've added the urls.py file to my initial piece

Comment: Add a trailing `/` to your path, like this: `path('add/', views.ProjectCreateView.as_view(), name='add'),`

Comment: Thanks Jordan M! that done the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you request `/add/` with the trailing slash, this does not match the `add` path but does match the `<slug:project_slug>/` path, so it tries your `project_detail` view with `project_slug` set to "add".